# What sort of privacy can be expected with Apple Business Manager enrolling a company Mac in a MDM?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, privacy, mdm, automated-device-enrollment

I got a new Macbook that is managed by a company with Apple Business Manager. Other than working for this company, I want to use this device for my private stuff too, like freelancing. This would mean storing some projects and applications on the device that I don't want to share with a company that owns this Macbook device - I want full privacy and control over my data.

The warning says the company can erase the device and list installed apps, but I’m not sure how to tell what else they might do with their owned and managed device.

It would be very helpful to know what extent of privacy and control I have over this managed device?

Comment: As you have learned - it matters which entitlements the ABM / MDM asks for - might you be able to upload a screen shot of what the MDM profile warning tells you specifically what control you are ceding? Is it to erase / track or something else? I’ve edited the question in case you are very happy with the answer provided. The door is open for the company to do lots of things based on the MDM they chose and if they own the mac - they can change MDM on their schedule without you being able to stop it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have full privacy and control over your own personal data on a MacBook that is managed by your employer. That is not possible.

You need to use a separate, private device for your own personal data and your own personal freelance business.

In addition to the actions you specify yourself (such as remote wiping and browsing installed apps), an employer also has almost limitless access to a managed computer - including the possibility to install and run custom scripts that perform all sorts of actions. That includes for example copying data to a company server.

Note that I'm not saying that your employer is spying on you or that they are copying your data. I'm just saying that it is technically possible to do things like that. The laws in your country as well as the contract you have with your employer will probably forbid or limit actions like that.

Comment: I would also look at your employment contract, it might well say that anything done on a company's machine belongs to them.

Comment: Thanks for reply and this tip. I have decided to buy new device for my private stuff.

Comment: You could also try asking why they want to manage your MacBook in the first place. If the answer is "something something security", you could try installing https://github.com/ParetoSecurity/pareto-mac/releases and showing them that security is taken care of.